# Tabs not triggering

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Have an issue with my tabs not expanding... [Link](https://colletts2021.wpengine.com/the-tyrol-bavarian-alps/) Having moved jQuery from the footer as WP is calling it from the header and updated the JavaScript for **$(function ()** { to **jQuery(function ($)** { I am at a loss as to why the tabs now wont open their respective active div.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ?

Comment: Thanks - Have read it all and will adhere to this in future posts - just getting to grips with stackoverflow. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I saw your Code I think it's because you set same id for two div for example try changing the second id

id="tabpyrenees"

```
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tabpyrenees">
              <div class="tours-tabs__content padding-all">
                  <div>
                    <div id="tabpyrenees" class="accordiontour" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
```

here is an example

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_tabs_dynamic&stacked=h

Comment: On the staging site I removed a second instance jQuery loading from the footer as in Wordpress it is being loaded in the header and was causing various conflicts.

Comment: I fixed the uncaught JavaScript error **from $(function () {** to **jQuery(function ($) {** and have tested the site. Everthing is functioning except the tabs - the tabs work fine on the [live site][1] (active tab ID's the same) where the jQuery is still being loaded from the footer but not on the [staging site][2].  
  [1]: https://www.colletts.co.uk/the-tyrol-bavarian-alps/
  [2]: https://colletts2021.wpengine.com/the-tyrol-bavarian-alps/